# my minecraft turns black on minecraft classic

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My minecraft java crashes 24/7 when i play version c.0.0.13.a_03 and version c.0.0.11.a and the other classic minecraft versions. My screen turns black and breaks down whenever I click something. Most of these versions don't work at all, I press the 'move' buttons like w/a/s/d or swipe my mouse around and they won't work. On version a1.04 on, it doesn't have this problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a separate directory for it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's probably just a bug (general or incompatibility). That's a very early version that was not tested well at all.

Also, if you use the same data folder as you used for a newer version before, that often leads to crashes.